# How to find index of a value in array of char?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have this array of `char`:

```
private char[] _alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                        .ToCharArray();
```

I want find the index of the character `B`, so the code must return 1.

I wrote this method:

```
public int? GetCharIndex(string code)
{
    return _alpha.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ToString() == code.ToUpper());
}
```

where `code` is `b`. The result of `GetCharIndex` is: 66, why I get this result?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Because 66 is the ASCII code of B. FirstOrDeafult does not return the index - it returns the first value for witch the expression "c.ToString() == code.ToUpper()" is true for.

Comment: You can add .Position to end the of your return statement chained with the FirstorDefault and it will return the index. Beware of Null reference errors

Comment: @Daniel I've no `.Position` method

Comment: What is your code variable value, is it b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Array.IndexOf

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2

The 66 you are getting is 'B' ascii value.

The FirstOrDefault function returns the actual item (B) not the index.

So:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(_alpha, code.ToUpper());
```

Comment: ohh looks like a typing issue too.
the array holds char but code is string. you could do code.ToUpper()[0] to get the first char of the string.
but you must be sure that it's the correct logic for you!
if you are typing the input (code) maybe right 'B' instead of "B". that will give you a char instead of a string.

Comment: there is no "find index" on enumerables, which is what linq uses. you should use Array.IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, you'd like to use Linq. The Select in LINQ has an override that let's you expose the index. Getting the first matching value will give us the index of the occurrence. You can also replace the `.FirstOrDefault()` to `.ToList()` if you want all indexes on the match.

**ToList**

```
char[] _alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray();

var code = "b";

var key = _alpha.Select((s, i) => new { i, s })
       .Where(t => t.s.ToString().ToUpper() == code.ToUpper())
       .Select(t => t.i)
       .ToList();
```

Alternatively the above can also be written as

**FirstOrDefault**

```
return _alpha.Select((s, i) => new { i, s }).FirstOrDefault(t => t.s.ToString().ToUpper() == code.ToUpper()).i;
```

Comment: this is a good approach for performance speed? Seems to much for a simple functionality

Comment: It depends on how you want to implement, if you want to use Fluent API then LINQ is the way to go, if you want to write your own (which you should avoid when you don't have to) then make your own method with a loop and return on the index

Comment: Rather than converting to uppercase you should use `string.Compare(t.s, code, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. With `ToUpper` & `ToLower`, what happens when the application runs on a PC with different locale settings - such as Turkish?

Answer (score 0):

> Why I get this result?

`Nullable<Char>` is implicitly convertible to `Nullable<Int32>` because `Char` is implicitly convertible to `Int32`. That happens in your return statement. You're returning the character from the array if found.

Where people are saying ASCII code, they mean character code; in particular, since  .NET uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set the UTF-16 code unit value.

BTW—VB4/5/6/A/Script, Java, JavaScript, … also use UTF-16 for text datatypes.

To use standard LINQ operators, choose one that supplies an index like `Select`:

```
Char[] _alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

Func<Char, StringComparison, Int32?> GetIndexOf = (code, comparisonType) => {
    var value = code.ToString();
    return _alpha
        .Select((c, i) => c.ToString()
           .Equals(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? i : (Int32?)null)
        .FirstOrDefault(i => i.HasValue); } ;

Debug.Assert(1 == GetIndexOf('B', StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
Debug.Assert(null == GetIndexOf('3', StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

And, you do have to decide what you really intend by your ".ToUpper". As a question/code review issue, it's unclear. It would be better to write your question and code (or at least as a code comment) in such a way as it explains what the proper culture is for letter case comparison. You used one that depends on the program's current culture, which is initialized from the user's culture at the time the program started.